# Reduce PDF file size

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, itext7

I used pdfHTML add-on in iText 7 to create an accessible PDF. The generated PDF has a high file size.
As an example, the 17 page PDF file has 3709KB. I used the below code to compress the PDF.

```
SetFullCompressionMode(true)
SetCompressionLevel(CompressionConstants.BEST_COMPRESSION)
```

It reduced file size 3709kB to 3396KB in small amount.

Is there any other way to reduce PDF file size?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: is the pdf composed by many images (jpeg, png)?

Comment: for reference a 25-page pdf I currently have is 866KB... I'd say pick a different library... there are quite a few choices

Comment: No it hasn't more images. There are one image (32KB), paragraphs and tables.

Comment: Well, post a link to the generated PDF maybe if we look at the contents of it might help...I've used iText 7 (iTextSharp) for many years and it works fine. A file size is determined by the contents it contains. A 5 page PDF can easily be 20MB so that reference by @hellyale is quite not so intuitive...

Comment: @Morgs a 20MB 5-page pdf is cancer, just because you can, doesn't mean you should. https://stackoverflow.com/a/612784/4645236

Comment: In addition to the pdf please post enough code to allow us to understand how you create the pdf and to allow us to give you tips how to improve your code. For example:  If you use multiple font objects and each time embed the whole font, not merely a subset, your pdf size obviously will explode.

Comment: @UweKeim raise a custom mod flag (rather than leave a comment) when you see things like this and we'll investigate voting fraud.

Comment: Could you open the resulting document in Acrobat (Pro), go to menu File --> Save as optimized, and in that dialog look at the results of Audit Space Usage. This should give you some hints where to look further. The "usual suspects" are images, fonts, and/or text converted to outlines.

Comment: I looked in to menu File --> Save as optimized, here fonts has used 47.6% and "Document overhead" has used 47.99%. How to reduce fonts usage ?

Comment: *"How to reduce fonts usage ?"* - by improving the way you use fonts. For more details you obviously have to share the information requested in previous comments.

Answer (score 1):

I could resolve this issue. In my case, I for my pdf doc, I have used 3 page events for the page footer, header and watermark text. Inside this page events, I had written below code to create font.

```
pdfFontFactory.CreateFont(font,pdfEncordings.IDENTITY_H,true);
```

I removed that one and create the font in once and pass it to each events.
Then page size is reduced to 3709kB to 2150KB.